# Timeline on rotating rectangle

Tags: javafx

I need to make one action happen while animation is half way there. Like my rectangle is rotating 180 degrees on Y Axis. I need it to change the color when 90 degrees is done and make text visible when 180 degrees is done.

I was told to use Timeline and add event handlers to the relevant key frames but I don't really know how.

```
public void open() {
  RotateTransition trans = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rec);
  trans.setOnFinished(event -> {
  text.setVisible(true);
  rec.setFill(Color.WHITE);
  });
  trans.play(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timeline` allows you to animate properties as well as triggering events at a given time. In the following example the `rotate` property of a rectangle is animated from 0 to 180 using 2 `KeyFrame`s for the initial rotate and the final rotate value (the first one isn't needed, unless you want to reverse the animation or play it more than once ect.; A bit more work would be required for the color in this case). An additional `KeyFrame` triggers a `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` which changes the `fill` of the `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);

Duration rotateDuration = Duration.seconds(5);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rec.rotateProperty(), 0)), // initial rotate
        new KeyFrame(rotateDuration.divide(2), evt -> {
            // event for halfway through
            rec.setFill(Color.RED);
        }),
        new KeyFrame(rotateDuration, new KeyValue(rec.rotateProperty(), 180)) // end value of rotate
);

timeline.play();
```

---

If you need to specify a pivot point, you could also apply a [`Rotate` transform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) to the `Node` and animate it's `angle` property:

```
Rotate rotate = new Rotate(0, pivotX, pivotY);
rec.getTransforms().add(rotate);

...
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 0)),
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! 

But I need a rotation around the center of the my triangle. I used RotateTransition for that but it doesn't seem to work in timeline?

Comment: @Felix it doesn't work with `Timeline`, but you could animate the `angle` property of a `Rotate` transform applied to the `Node`.

Comment: yes, it now works perfectly! `Rotate rt = new Rotate(0, 20, 30, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS)`